# Wall Feels Solid-- Can't Hang Art

Tags: drywall, walls, plaster, hanging

So, I've been trying to hang some canvas art for a bit, but my border wall (bordering another apartment) feels solid and I can't get more than a little over 1cm deep with a Monkey Hook. Initially I assumed I was hitting a stud so I switched positions 2 more times just to make sure, still no dice.

I'm assuming it's either plaster (so wooden laths behind all the surface) or there's something like brick separating apartment rooms for sound proofing, or finally, something behind the wall that need not be punctured.

I called maintenance so I'll get a response tomorrow either way, but I was really hoping to finally finish this before the work week starts.

Any ideas? Maybe someone has had a similar situation? And if it *is* something that I won't be able to pierce through with a Monkey Hook, what should I use instead?

Thanks,
E

[image]

Comment: In an apartment building the walls need to be fireproof. Often that means they are concrete.  Try a sticky wall hook, like a Command Strip.

Comment: How heavy is the art you want to hang?

Answer (score 1):

Hard wall picture hooks (or hardwall picture hooks) are a thing.  They are usually plastic with three or four small sharp pins inserted.  Hold the hook where you want it, and use a hammer to drive the pins into the wall.